# How to prove the convexity of $f$ if the strict epigraph of $f$ is convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I have trouble to prove the equivalence of the following two definitions of convex function. For convenience, I list them as follows:

Def-A. Let $f : I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, where $I$ is (and from now on) an interval in $\mathbb{R}.$ We call $f$ is convex on $I,$ if for every pair of $x_1, x_2\in I$ with $x_1\neq x_2,$ and for all $\lambda \in (0,1),$ we have 
\begin{gather*}
f\big(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2\big)\leq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda )f(x_2).
\end{gather*}

Def-B. Let $f: I\to \mathbb{R},$ we call the set
\begin{gather*}
\text{epi}(f):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid  x\in I, y\geq f(x)\}
\end{gather*} 
the epigraph of $f.$

Def-C. Let $f: I\to\mathbb{R},$ we call the set
\begin{gather*}
\text{epi}_s(f):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid  x\in I, y> f(x)\}
\end{gather*} 
the strict epigraph of $f.$

As usual, we have known that $f: I\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex on $I$ if and only if the epigraph of $f,$ that is $\text{epi}(f)$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

But recently we I read Giaquinta and Modica's book Mathemtical Analysis, Functions of one variable, I found that in Page 226, they called the strict epigraph of $f$ here (see Def-C above) the epigraph of $f,$ that is to say, they call $\text{epi}_s(f)$ the epigraph of $f,$ and claimed that 
\begin{gather*}\tag{$\star$}
\text{$f$ is convex on $I,$ if and only if $\text{epi}_s (f) $ is convex.}
\end{gather*}
 Then, I tried to prove $(\star).$  I have finished proof of that $\text{epi}_s(f)$ is convex, if $f$ is convex on $I.$ But when I tried to prove the converse, I was stuck!

Then, my question is, how to prove that $f$ is convex on $I,$  provided $\text{epi}_s(f)$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Comment: I may be missing something (indeed, very likely) but I see no difference between the two epigraph definitions B and C.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Sorry for my careless, I have corrected.

Comment: @Nameless, Yes, you can use, if you can show the equivalence of the convexity of $\text{epi}_s(f)$ with the strict convexity of $f.$

Comment: @azc, I'll come back tomorrow and check.

Comment: Are you able to prove (or assume) the standard result---the convexity of f implies the convexity of the non-strict epigraph? If so, then your challenge reduces to showing that the convexity of the non-strict epigraph implies the convexity of the strict epigraph. For most convex functions, if not all, the strict epigraph is just the relative interior of the epigraph, and the relative interior operation preserves convexity.

Comment: I just confirmed: the strict epigraph is *not* always the relative interior of the epigraph. It is the case only if the domain of $f$ (in your case, the interval $I$) is a relatively open set (in your case, an open interval).

Comment: Indeed, in Giaquinta & Modica's book, Mathematical Analysis, Functions of One Variable,  they demand that $I$ is a bounded closed interval in $\mathbb{R},$ and thus claim that, for every function $f : I\to\mathbb{R},$  $f$ is convex, if and only if the strict epigraph of $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^2.$  I have proved the Necessity part of this claim, and was stuck when tried to prove the sufficiency part.

Answer (score 4):

> **Proposition:**
>   $$
> \text{epi}(f)=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\bigl(\text{epi}_S(f)-(0,\epsilon)\bigr).
> $$
>   *Proof:*
>   A simple observation 
>   $$
> f(x)\le y\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\forall\epsilon>0\colon \ f(x)<y+\epsilon
> $$ 
>   leads directly to
>   $$
> (x,y)\in\text{epi}(f)\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \forall\epsilon>0\colon \ (x,y+\epsilon)\in\text{epi}_S(f)\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad 
> $$
>   $$
> \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \forall\epsilon>0\colon \ (x,y)\in\text{epi}_S(f)-(0,\epsilon)\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad (x,y)\in\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\bigl(\text{epi}_S(f)-(0,\epsilon)\bigr).
> $$

Now if $\text{epi}_S(f)$ is convex then the translations $\text{epi}_S(f)-(0,\epsilon)$ are convex as well and, hence, $\text{epi}(f)$ is convex as an itersection of convex sets.

Comment: It looks like this proof is true in general -- not just in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a closed/bounded domain, as mentioned in the book. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Zim Absolutely, it works for any dimension.

Comment: If the epigraph is convex, how does this proof yield convexity of the strict epigraph?

Comment: @Zim The answer does not prove this direction as the OP has mentioned it to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I am adapting the proof from [Convexity and Optimization in Banach Spaces](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-007-2247-7_2) from my own interpretation.

Since $\text{epi} f$ is strictly convex, this means for the pair of points $(x,\alpha), (y,\beta) \in \text{epi}  f$ we have the condition $$f(z) < t\alpha + (1-t)\beta,$$

where $t\in[0,1]$ and $z = tx + (1-t)y.$ We are required to show that $f(z) \leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)$, but we will instead assume on the contrary that we have $$f(z) > tf(x) + (1-t)f(y).$$

Consider the set $$\mathcal{A} = \{ (1-t)\alpha + t\beta: (x,\alpha),(y, \beta) \in \text{epi}(f)\}.$$

This set is nonempty and bounded below (this follows from the fact neither $f(x)$ or $f(y)$ can be equal to $+\infty$), thus $\mathcal{A}$ admits an infinium.

Therefore the chain of inequality shows,

$$f(z)  \leq \inf \mathcal{A} = (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) <f(z).$$

This leads to a contradiction, so we conclude our original assumption is incorrect.